# Android Two Pane Layout, no view found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Right now my app works fine at regular screen.
I am having a tough time figuring out how I can manage my current UI to handle the two panel layout.

Right now my DetailActivity has some UI elements to load, 3 fragments on separate tabs, controls what each FAB does, FAB animation and a fragment page adapter for the tab layout.

What should I do to manage all of these elements and logics in a separate class and also in the main activity for the two pane layout?

**Here is my Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static boolean TWO_PANE;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (findViewById(R.id.movie_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the large-screen layouts
        // (res/layout-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the activity should be
        // in two-pane mode.
        TWO_PANE = true;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
    }else{
        TWO_PANE = false;
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new FragmentMain())
            .commit();
}
```

Fragment Main displays a movie grid layout, when clicked if it's regular phone open another activity, otherwise the movie details should display at the right corner.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Defines the xml file for the fragment
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getContext());
    gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    //Start DetailActivity with the movie details.
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            if (MainActivity.TWO_PANE){
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable(Constants.BUNDLE_CONSTANT, mMovieElements.get(position));
                FragmentDetail fragment = new FragmentDetail();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                getChildFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.movie_detail_container, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }else{
                //Starting detail activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mMovieElements.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

**land\Activity-main:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".ui.ui.MainActivity">

<!--
This layout is activity_main two-pane layout for the Items master/detail flow.
-->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    class = "com.joaonogueira.nmovies.ui.ui.FragmentMain"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:name="com.joaonogueira.nmovies.ui.ui.FragmentDetail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_container"
    tools:context="com.joaonogueira.nmovies.ui.ui.DetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
                android:id="@+id/posterImage"
                android:background="@drawable/nopicture"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/MovieContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My Fragment Detail doesn't start, I am getting the following error:

> No view found for id 0x7f0c0070 (com.joaonogueira.nmovies:id/movie_detail_container) for fragment FragmentDetail{1b71bc14 #0 id=0x7f0c0070 bundle}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to replace a fragment from the fragment itself

```
getChildFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.movie_detail_container, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

But since `movie_detail_container` is not present in the fragment view and is a part of the activity layout instead, hence you are getting that error.

What you need to do is to have a listener interface implemented in your activity and make your fragment listen to that. Finally, you invoke that listener to make your activity replace a new fragment.
If you don't know how to do that read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Comment: thank you so much. All working now. I thought that when i use getChildFragmentManager i was calling the previous activity.